# Site not globally available

Tags: web-hosting, dns, nameserver, dns-servers, route53

This is the site: https://za.mojcoek.mk
 - I received reports from multiple locations that it's not available.

The config goes like this:

- The **.mk** registrar points to AWS Route53 hosting zone for the **mojcoek.mk** domain
- Route 53 points to a different hosting provider just for the subdomain **za.mojcoek.mk**, where that WordPress site is hosted.

Reported this to the hosting provider, they said it's not their fault.

Here's my Route53 configuration:

[image]

Comment: Site is up and running
    https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/za.mojcoek.mk

Comment: Yeah. Based on THAT sevice.

Comment: You have a lame delegation, the NS RRSet between parent and child are not the same and the nameservers have various errors, look at http://dnsviz.net/d/za.mojcoek.mk/XCZfkg/dnssec/  You will first need to improve your DNS setup.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I'm by no means an expert in dns management, so it's actually great that you found something out. Could you please spell some of these things out for me? What exactly do I need to do? I'm providing my Route53 setup.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek why give up so easily.

Comment: Why did you put NS records for `za.mojcoek.mk`? What are you trying to achieve? Why not just using an `A` or `CNAME` record? You do not need `NS` records to point at another hosting provider. But since you are using an hosting provider, they should be able to help you set things correctly, did you ask them?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek well, Route53 explains that `A` only accepts IP addresses. I achieved what I wanted, with the bug I explained: "Route 53 points to a different hosting provider just for the subdomain za.mojcoek.mk, where that WordPress site is hosted". I don't understand how using `CNAME` would solve this. I did ask my hosting provider, they said everything is fine.

Comment: An `A` record maps an hostname to an IP address, so it would have been used to map your `za.mojcoek.mk` to your hosting provider server IP address. Or a `CNAME` records that maps one name to another, if the hosting provider prefers not to give you IP addresses so that he remains free to change them without you having to update anything. Anyway if your problem is solved, please accept one answer (or answer it yourself) so that it is marked as closed and can benefit others.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I still don't quite understand what are you suggesting. `CNAME` instead of `NS`? Why? No, the problem is not solved.

Comment: I still do not understand why you use `NS` records your case is not clear. To do hosting, you need to map names to IP addresses, which is done with a combination of `A`, `AAAA` and `CNAME` records. You do not need `NS` records and if you do not know well how the DNS works I advise not to touch `NS` records otherwise you are exactly in your situation that is a lame delegation that will create problems. Again, this is a job for your hosting provider to explain to you and help you with; if they do not want to help you set up your DNS records correctly, you may have to think about changing.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek funny enough, I still don't understand your practical suggestion : }  should replacing my `NS` record with a `CNAME` be enough?

Comment: Yes, probably/maybe/normally. It depends on your hosting provider. If they do not want to help you since you are left with finding other users in your same case or trial and errors attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Just accesed your site. It's working fine.

I guess the problem that you faced was this:

Due to large TTL DNS servers across the world take time to update CNAMES and A Records. probably the DNS server that you accessed did not have the CNAME directing to your server. Now it must be probably up over there too. Check [DNS Checker](https://dnschecker.org/#A/za.mojcoek.mk) to check your domain details

[[image: Image of your website[1]]

Comment: It's actually still happening. I know one of the users tho, is there anything I can do using their network to figure out where exactly is the problem?